# Javascript таймер с паузой и продолжить

Tags: javascript

Есть таймер, который отсчитывает минуту.
Есть кнопки "пауза", "начать заново" и "продолжить".
Первая и вторая отрабатывают, а вот последняя не работает.
Подскажите, куда копать?

```js
    if(channel == 'stopTimer') {
  timer_on = false;
        return;
    }
 if(channel == 'continueTimer') {
  timer_on = true;
        return;
    }
    
    if (channel == 'AddTime') {
        timer_on = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            timer_on = true;
            startTimer(TimeToAdd * 60);
        }, 1e3);
        return;   
    }
```

Вот сама функция:

```js
function startTimer(time)
{
    TimerProcceed = true;
    var time_def = time;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if(timer_on == true) {
        time--;
        postTime(time, time_def);
  }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Вам нужно переписать функцию, сам таймер нельзя ставить на паузу, можно только начать отчет сначала. Возможно передавать параметр, сколько времени прошло со старта таймера и начинать таймер исходя из этих данных